# Jetbrains IDE chrome extention - how can I install it offline?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm developing on an offline machine and I need to install the IDE chrome extention. Since my machine has no internet connection, I can't get to the chrome app store.
I've searched my online webstorm install for the jb.rcx file but it doesn't exist.  Is there a way to install this manually offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no:( you can only download it from Chrome WebStore - there is no other way to install the extension.